# Refresh the view controller from popover

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, refresh, popover

I have a view controller which has 100 pages (every page is different), from this controller I open a popover view and inside this popover there are buttons which are planned to change the pages.  For example, if "number 10" button is pressed from popover, the 10th page should come in view controller. But I couldn't implement it. The code passes the view controller and to the correct method but the page doesnt change and also the popover view controller is not dismissed.
I miss something but what is that?
If someone can help me, I'll be so glad.

PS. i dont use tableview

Kind regards, 
Can

Answer (score 0):

first of, who's your PopOver delegate? Our UIViewController? Is he a [UIPopOverControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307)? If yes, have you implemented, for example this method:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

So you know when it was dismissed? Give me some feedback. :)

Comment: Yes, my PopOver delegate is View Controller. Actually, I haven't implemented any methods about it, I just tried [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; Where should I implement that example method? Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: I mean should I implement in delegate class or in popover class?

Comment: You should implement that method in your popover's delegate (aka the view that calls your popover).  No problem glad to help mate. :D