# iOS: Refresh a ViewController from a popOver

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm working on a problem where I have a ViewController which opens a popOver when a button is pressed and then in the popOver you can edit some settings which affect the content shown in the mother ViewController (for instance change the color of the View, change a map or a table there). This can be off course called whenever the popOver is dismissed, but it needs to be live up-to-date.

I tried using delegates, where I can pass over data or call a function but the function won't be started on a ViewController wchich isn't active, right?
I also tried NSNotifications but it didn't work either.

I found several questions like this on stackoverflow, but there is no real answer yet:

- [UIPopoverController button selecting method of another ViewController but not updating its view iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956801/uipopovercontroller-button-selecting-method-of-another-viewcontroller-but-not-up)
- [Refresh the view controller from popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829922/refresh-the-view-controller-from-popover)
- [Refreshing a view from a popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233220/refreshing-a-view-from-a-popover)
- [Refresh a WebView in a ViewController from another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289248/refresh-a-webview-in-a-viewcontroller-from-another-viewcontroller)
- [how to refresh or reload a uiviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647870/how-to-refresh-or-reload-a-uiviewcontroller)

Can somebody please explain a generall way with some code snippets how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Delegation is a fine solution. The target view controller is presumably still visible underneath the popover (which shouldn't fill the screen). In this case when the target receives the delegate callback it can do any updates and refresh its views to update the UI without any limitation. In this situation both view controllers (the 'target' and the popover) would both be classed as 'active' as they are both visible on screen.